# script name in setup.py, why do I need file extension for script filename?

Tags: python, distutils

Related to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404258/distutils-not-a-regular-file-skipped/11709778#11709778)--I am very new to using setup.py to distribute python packages.

According to [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts), when passing script parameters to setup() in the setup.py file, it looks like you should use the script name without file extension.

```
setup(...,
      scripts=['scripts/xmlproc_parse', 'scripts/xmlproc_val']
      )
```

However, I found for my own test case that I needed to add the ".py" extension to the script parameter in order for packaging to work.  E.g.:

```
config = {...
    'scripts': ['bin/testscript3.py'],
    }
....

setup(**config)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is that the expected behavior?  My guess is that this is expected, but I am just confused by the python documentation.  I do realize this may have a trivial explanation, but after some googling I couldn't figure it out, and maybe some other newbies will benefit from this question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write the script name exactly as it is represented on your file system.

I think you're confused by the documentation as, on some platforms (Unix), filename extensions are not a standard way to choose in which program a file will be executed (look for "[unix shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)" if you want to learn more), so, often, there is not filenames extensions on scripts.

Comment: Thanks! An even more trivial answer than I expected :)
-> ANSWER: when I use scripts "for real", I may hide the file extension to make it easier to run / use.